# $@ vs. "$@" when an argument is enclosed with single quotes

Tags: arrays, bash

**So the following commands are giving me different answers than I expect.**

Code:

```
#!/bin/sh

array_2=('1 2' 3 4)

echo With '"$@":'

for i in "${array_2[@]}"
do
    echo $i
done


echo With '$@:'

for i in ${array_2[@]}
do
    echo $i
done
```

Output:

```
With "$@":
1 2
3
4


With $@:
1
2
3
4
```

Why is **$@** "not seeing" that '1 2' are enclosed by single quotes, when **"$@"** can?

Comment: Variables are not expanded inside single quotes.

Comment: Somebody posted this and was deleted but here it is again, this will/should give you the answers you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable